# Is this output of XQuery correct?

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm doing practice in XQuery and have some questions. Are these outputs for the given XQueries correct?

```
let $i := ("a","b"), $j := 1 to 2
return ($i,$j)
```

Output:

```
a b 1 2
```

and

```
for $i in ("a","b"), $j in 1 to 2
return ($i,$j)
```

Output:

```
a 1
a 2
b 1
b 2
```

Can someone confirm that these are these results are correct?

Comment: They are correct. Could you please add some information on why you would expect another result?

Comment: i tried this queries in BaseX and got the outputs as          


a
b
1
2

and 
 
a
1
a
2
b
1
b
2

Comment: there are not in a line but every single character in a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have formatted the responses for clarity, yes the output of those two FLWOR statements are correct.

The first expression creates two variables that have a sequence of values.

```
let $i := ("a","b"), $j := 1 to 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
let $i := ("a","b"), $j := (1, 2)
```

So, `return ($i,$j)` is equivalent to:

```
( ("a", "b"), (1, 2) )
```

Since [Sequences never contain other sequences; if sequences are combined, the result is always a “flattened” sequence.](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#sequences), then the result is the following sequence:

```
("a", "b", 1, 2)
```

---

The second expression

```
for $i in ("a","b"), $j in 1 to 2
return ($i,$j)
```

is equivalent to writing the following nested for loop:

```
for $i in ("a","b")
return
  for $j in (1, 2)
  return ($i, $j)
```

which produces:

```
( ("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1), ("b", 2) )
```

which is then flattened to the following sequence of values:

```
("a", 1, "a", 2, "b", 1, "b", 2)
```